# Reading data and filter to insert it into template

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, python-docx

I am creating a program that allows me to read the tables of an excel file of all the sheets and asks the user to enter the name of the available teacher to extract all the subjects and print them in table form in a word template.
How could you help me so that this code runs correctly with what I want to do?

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from tabulate import tabulate
from docx import Document

def filtrar_y_exportar_excel_a_word(archivo_excel, campo_filtro, valor_filtro, archivo_word):
    # Leer el archivo Excel
    df = pd.read_excel(archivo_excel)

    # Filtrar el DataFrame según el campo y el valor proporcionados
    df_filtrado = df[df[campo_filtro] == valor_filtro]

    # Crear un nuevo documento Word
    doc = Document()

    # Agregar una tabla al documento Word
    table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=len(df.columns), style='Table Grid')

    # Agregar encabezados de columna a la tabla
    for col_num, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
        table.cell(0, col_num).text = col_name

    # Agregar filas de datos a la tabla
    for _, row in df_filtrado.iterrows():
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
        for col_num, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
            row_cells[col_num].text = str(row[col_name])

    # Guardar el documento Word
    doc.save(archivo_word)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    archivo_excel = "c:/ProyTerminal/Util/PAEG_23O_LTSI_V3_11122023.xlsx"  #  ruta de tu archivo Excel
    campo_filtro = "PROFESOR POSIBLE"  #  el nombre de tu campo de filtro
    valor_filtro = "Tiburcio Moreno"  #  el valor que deseas filtrar
    archivo_word = "c:/ProyTerminal/Util/documento.docx"  #  la ruta donde deseas guardar el nuevo documento Word

    filtrar_y_exportar_excel_a_word(archivo_excel, campo_filtro, valor_filtro, archivo_word)
```

How could you help me so that this code runs correctly with what I want to do?

Comment: Please don't load up your question with irrelevant tags.  This question has nothing to do with "java", "html" or "css".  Tag spamming is (to say the least!) inconsiderate of people who watch tags for relevant questions to answer.